# React Native - How to change data in js file using text input

Tags: react-native

My android app is loading string data from a js file that is looking like this:

```
module.exports = {
DATA: {
  firstdata: 'data',
  seconddata: 'data2'},
};
```

What I want to do, is change content of this file using text input with

```
 onChangeText={(text) => data.DATA.firstdata.setState({text})}
```

But it tells me that "undefined is not a function".

These are my first attempts with text inputs. Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: There are a few typos, unsure if the code is verbatim. data2 is missing an apostrophe for example before the }

Comment: Fixed. I rewrote small part just for an example, real file has lot more data

Answer (score 0):

it seems you are trying to implement different concepts. You are trying to change js file using setState function, which is a function provided by react to change data in local component state. So, in your case, `data.DATA.firstdata` should be just a string, that doesn't know what setState function is. But, according to an error, it seems you are not even importing this DATA variable.

What you can do is set this data to your local state when component is mounted, and then mutate this local state with setState function.

```
...
import { DATA } from './path/to/the/file'

class MyComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            firstdata: DATA.firstdata,
            seconddata: DATA.seconddata,
        };
    }
    render() {
        return (
            ...

           <TextInput onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({firstdata: text})}>
        )
    }
}
```